# Field theory (fractions)

Tags: ring-theory

I've been studying the field of fractions and am comfortable with the basic construction. I'm more interested in what happens when the inital Integral Domain is itself a Field.

For example Zmod13. Obviously this is a finite field so I could list it's equivalence classes, am I right in thinking they would be something of the form:
[0,m]={(x,y),(a,b): x,y,a,b belong to zmod7 and y and b don't equal 0}

I'm then not too sure if I can still consider this equivalnece class as something of the form 0/m like I would be able to for the field of fractions constructed from the integers. If I can then I would be able to simplify [0,m] to just [0]?

Answer (score 1):

The field of fractions of a field is the field itself...

This can be seen easily by the universal property characterising the field of fractions:

> Let $R$ be a ring. The field of fractions $Q(R)$ of $R$ satisfies the following property: if $h:R\to k$ is an injective ring homomorphism into a field, then there exists a unique field homomorphism $H$ extending $h$.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I'm aware of this and have shown that they are isomorphic to one another, but I'm still not sure what the elements would be in the example given. I'm guessing it'll have 13 distinct elements corresponding to [0],[1]...,[12]? Could I write for example [0] the way I did in my inital post? Apologies for any confusion.

Comment: @hazza777 Oh, ok. Then see ClémentGuérin's answer below.

Answer (score 1):

One way to see the field of fractions associated to an integral domain $R$ is that it is the "smallest field" that contains $R$, so that if $R$ happens to be a field $Frac(R)$ will be $R$ since it is already a field.

Now formally, $Frac(R)$ is the quotient of $R\times R^*$ by the relation $(a,b)\equiv (c,d)$ if $ad=bc$. An element of $Frac(R)$ is then $[a,b]$ the class of such a pair.

There is an inclusion of $R$ within $Frac(R)$ given by $r\mapsto [r,1]$. Now because $R$ is a field, I claim that any element $(a,b)$ is equivalent to some $(r,1)$, this is because $(a,b)\equiv (ab^{-1},1)$ so that $Frac(R)=\{[a,b]|(a,b)\in R\times R^*\}=\{[ab^{-1},1]\mid (a,b)\in R\times R^*\}=\{[r,1]\mid r\in R\}$.

Comment: Clément Guérin thanks for the help. So then in Frac(Zmod13) [0]={[0,1] | 0 belongs to Zmod13} and in general the list of all the equivalence classes in Zmod13 is just Frac(Zmod13)={[r,1] | r belongs to Zmod13}?

Comment: @hazza777, yes the class of $[0,m]$ always denotes $0$, what is important is that because every non-zero element of $R$ is invertible you can always transform the second element of a couple to a $1$ by equivalence. If we write this differently $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{ab^{-1}}{1}$ which is in $R$ because the denominator is $1$.

Comment: I think I'm beginning to understand more. So just to double check [2] in Frac(Zmod13) would be {[2,1] | 2 belongs to Zmod13}?

Comment: @hazza777 No, $[2,1]=\{(2r,r)\mid r\in R^*\}=[4,2]=[6,3]=...$ in $Frac(Z_{13})$ is corresponding to $2$ in $Z_{13}$.  Your last set is a subset of $Frac(Z_{13})$ with one element, not one element of $Frac(Z_{13})$.